# How to provide SSL to docker containers?

Tags: node.js, docker, nginx, ssl

I am trying to create a online cloud based IDE just like replit.com. Whenever user creates a new project, I spin a docker container on AWS ECS Fargate.

I also generate a unique URL for each project. FOr example: project1.example.com, project2.example.com. To achive this I have my own DNS that maps URL to an IP address stored in my DB.

The problem is that I have a SSL certificate (Let's Encrypt) which is valid for *.example.com (Entire Subdomain) but how to proxy the SSL certitficate.

Do I need to put the copy of SSL certificate in each docker instance or is there somthing else I can do?

Lets say my DNS is running on EC2 machine on ns1.example.com

project1.example.com --> docker instance
project2.example.com --> docker instance

How to manage single SSL certificate to be used in all docker instances that are dynamically created and destroyed.

Thanks in advance

I tried to make an nginx proxy server that accepts all requests from *.example.com and proxy_pass to docker instance. but I am not able to achive this as I can't dynamically fetch IP address in nginx.

Comment: you can create one base docker image use it to build al other docker so by default cert will be there. by any can't you run you container on HTTP ? set SSL at LB level terminate it simply there from LB to container it will be HTTP traffic.

Comment: Is there any way that I can dynamically proxy requests in nginx? For example, project1.example.com -> 1.2.3.4, project2.example.com -> 3.4.5.6. All these mappings are stored in my database.

Comment: got that so you want to route it IPs ? or based on URL params logic something to backed service name?

Comment: Just proxy pass to the ip address. IP address is stored in Database.

Answer (score 0):

Your can build base docker image from nginx image, which contain ssl certificats and usage this image for up docker container. Also look on 'portworx' it shared storage driver for docker and kubernetes.